# Grouping in a list with sequence re-read

Tags: python, list

I have a string (Ex: BCVDBCVCBCBD) which i have converted into a list using the

```
seq_split = [string[i:i+1] for i in range (0, len(string),1)]
```

This resulted in a list like ['B' ,'C','V'.........,'D']

Now considering I take a user input, in the form of a number (say for example 2). I need to read every 2nd element from the start i.e 1st letter of sequence and the letter that is 2 positions away from the 1st letter (in count itll be the 3rd letter from start). The second time ill need to read the 2nd letter in the sequence and again the letter 2 positions away. i.e. the 2nd and 4th letter of the sequence  . (I know its a little confusing so heres a detailed explanation)

If the user input is the number 2:
Then in a new list i will need to append (using the given string as example)- 'BV' , 'CD' , 'VB' and so on in a new list.

Similarly if the input is 4. Then the new list i create will have - 'BB', 'CC' etc...
 I am confused as to how do i index them.

Comment: First off: `seq_split = list('BCVDBCVCBCBD')` does your first step

Comment: First off, there is no reason to convert your string to a list to achieve this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can get the desired list with

```py
[x + y for x, y in zip(string, string[i:])]
```

where `i` is the number chosen by the user.  Example:

```py
>>> string = "BCVDBCVCBCBD"
>>> i = 2
>>> [x + y for x, y in zip(string, string[i:])]
['BV', 'CD', 'VB', 'DC', 'BV', 'CC', 'VB', 'CC', 'BB', 'CD']
```

Comment: Very elegant (+1), but it would take linear space, which might be problematic with large lists

Comment: @inspectorG4dget: *Every* solution to this problem will use O(n) additional space, since this is the size of the result.  I admit that your solution is more memory-efficient. :)

Comment: Oh that is just brilliant. I did get the 'zip' function of the net, but could not understand as to what it was doing. also i was already creating a list and then trying to work on it. The function you gave here cancels out the need to use a created list. Saves a lot of headache.

Answer (score 4):

```
In [31]: L
Out[31]: ['B', 'C', 'V', 'D', 'B', 'C', 'V', 'C', 'B', 'C', 'B', 'D']

In [32]: sep = 2

In [33]: [L[i]+L[i+sep] for i in range(len(L)-sep)]
Out[33]: ['BV', 'CD', 'VB', 'DC', 'BV', 'CC', 'VB', 'CC', 'BB', 'CD']

In [34]: sep = 4

In [35]: [L[i]+L[i+sep] for i in range(len(L)-sep)]
Out[35]: ['BB', 'CC', 'VV', 'DC', 'BB', 'CC', 'VB', 'CD']
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/usr/bin/python
l = 'BCVDBCVCBCBD'
while True:
    try:
        step = int (raw_input('> '))
    except ValueError:
        import sys
        sys.exit(0);
    print map(
            lambda pos: ''.join(
                (
                    l[pos%len(l)],                                                                                                             
                    l[(pos+step)%len(l)]
                )),
            xrange(0, len(l))
            )
```

output:

```
@delphi# python manglechars.py 
> 2
['BV', 'CD', 'VB', 'DC', 'BV', 'CC', 'VB', 'CC', 'BB', 'CD', 'BB', 'DC']
> 3
['BD', 'CB', 'VC', 'DV', 'BC', 'CB', 'VC', 'CB', 'BD', 'CB', 'BC', 'DV']
> 4
['BB', 'CC', 'VV', 'DC', 'BB', 'CC', 'VB', 'CD', 'BB', 'CC', 'BV', 'DD']
>
```

Comment: This has a wrap-around. Nice!